# c++ STL map::find()

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I use my own class as a key type for std::map. How the map implementation determines when two objects are equal?

I know that I can determine operator< or Comp type to arrange elements. But I can find nothing about equality.

Comment: @chris That's an answer, not a comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to make the comparison using just `operator<`, so it doesn't require you to define `operator==` as well. Basically, if one is not less than the other, and the other is not less than the first, they must be equal. This is a possible utility function implementation of such:

```
bool isEqual(const Type &arg1, const Type &arg2) const {
    return !(arg1 < arg2) && !(arg2 < arg1);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `std::map<K, V, Comp>` class actually doesn't determine if objects are equal! All it cares about is if two objects are part of the same equivalence class which it determines using

```
Comp comp;
if (!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)) {
    // a and b are in the same equivalence class
}
```

The default definition of `Compo` is `std::less<K>`, i.e., the class determines equivalence as neither object being smaller than the other.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about being able to choose the comparison. That's always a good thing to include.